# For Loop Only Filling the Last Position in This Matrix Without The Correct Separator

Tags: r, string, for-loop, concatenation

When running the following code

```
test <- function(p){

  set.seed(1984)

  for(i in 1:p){

    x <- matrix()

    n <- function(){sample(1:10, size = 1)}

    draws <- function(){sample(LETTERS[1:10], n(), replace = T)}

    x[i] <- paste(draws(), sep = '-', collapse = '')

    }

  return(x)

}
```

R returns the following output:

```
> test(10)
 [1] NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   "GE"
```

When I am expecting to see this matrix filled with random (number of) letters in each row separated by dashes (`-`).

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to move `x <- matrix()` outside your `for` loop.

Comment: doh.  any ideas about the '-' separator? @Jthorpe

Comment: you want `collapse = '-'`; `sep` joins the arguments of `paste()`

Comment: It might also be an idea to move `set.seed(1984)` outside the definition of `test()` (which at the moment produces a vector not a matrix)

Comment: @Henry just put that in there for the post, apologies.  why does it produce a vector when i initialized with `x <- matrix()`?

Comment: When i=2, using `x[i] <- ...` seems to tell R you did not really mean a matrix.  How many rows or columns is it supposed to have?

Comment: See [`?matrix`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html): the default number of rows and colunms is one; when you assign out side scope of a 1xn matrix using a single index (i.e. `x = matrix(1:4); x[5] = 3`) R coerces the matrix to a vector since it had only one dimension to begin with.  (R does a good bit of type coercion that you won'd find in other languages).

Comment: @Henry it's doing to have to be a dynamic length, but I totally understand yours and jthorpe's point

Comment: A vector can be of dynamic length

Comment: @Henry - true, but I have to build-out some other columns for this thing :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting various comments from Jthorpe and me together, you might consider

```
test <- function(p){
  x <- character()
  for(i in 1:p){
    n <- function(){sample(1:10, size = 1)}
    draws <- function(){sample(LETTERS[1:10], n(), replace = T)}
    x[i] <- paste(draws(), collapse = '-')
    }
  return(as.matrix(x))
}

set.seed(1984)
test(10)
```

which produces a matrix with dashes between letters

```
      [,1]                 
 [1,] "E-D-D-H-I-A-E"      
 [2,] "C-I-A-H-H-C-A-C-G"  
 [3,] "C-G-A-G-I-H-B-I-F-F"
 [4,] "J-D-F-H-A-E"        
 [5,] "D-A-C-I-C-G"        
 [6,] "C-G-I-E"            
 [7,] "G-F-B-F-B"          
 [8,] "A-C-A-I-C-B-I-A"    
 [9,] "H-H-I"              
[10,] "G-E"
```